# Is there any positive function $f$ such that $f(x)f(y)\leq |x-y|$ for every $x$ rational and $y$ irrational?

Tags: analysis, functional-equations

> We are given a function $f$ from reals to positive reals (not including $0)$ satisfying 
>   $$f(x)f(y)\leq |x-y|$$
>   for every rational number $x$ and irrational number $y$. Does this function exist?

If $f$ is continuous, it is easy to show that $f$ must be a constant zero function (So it does not exist, in this case).

Otherwise, for an irrational number $y$ it can be shown that for any sequence $x_n$ of rationals converging to $y$, $f(x_n)$ converges to zero and the same is true for rational number $x$ and the sequence of irrationals $y_n$.

Does this argument give us any information about $f$, and does it say whether $f$ exists at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

$$A_k = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} : f(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{k} \right\}.$$

Let $a \in \mathbb{Q}, k \in \mathbb{N}$. For each $b \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ we have $\displaystyle f(b) \leqslant \frac{|b-a|}{f(a)}$, so there is an open neighborhood $U_a^{(k)} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of $a$ such that $U_a^{(k)} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \subseteq A_k$, namely $U_a^{(k)} = (a-r, a+r)$ where $r = \frac{f(a)}{k}$.

The union $\displaystyle G_k = \bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{Q}} U_a^{(k)} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a dense open set such that $G_k \setminus \mathbb{Q} \subseteq A_k$. Hence

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} G_k \setminus \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k,$$

therefore the set on the right is comeager in $\mathbb{R}$, so it must be non-empty. That is a contradiction.

P.S. Did you come up with this question studying the (lack of) $\mathrm{T}4$ property of the [Moore plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane)?

Comment: @Adayah..can you explain your answer..because it seems interesting and i want to understand it..

Comment: @MariosGretsas Sure, but could you be more specific about which part needs to be explained? Generally it uses the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Comment: My question is why did you take the sets $A_k$ and how you found for every k a dense set

Comment: @MariosGretsas I included some details to answer the second question. As to the first, I really don't know how to explain it. I noticed that every point in $\mathbb{Q}$ has a neighborhood in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ where $f$ is $k$-small, i.e. $f(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{k}$, so the set where $f$ is $k$-small is open dense. With some practice, the Baire category theorem easily comes to mind in this situation, which yields that there are points where $f$ is $k$-small for each $k$, which is impossible. That was my idea.